# MySQL multiple retrieves

Tags: php, mysql

How would I retrieve the information without calling multiple fetches?

```
for ($course_period=1; $course_period<=4; $course_period++) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id=".$course[$course_period]["id"]);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $course[$course_period]["name"] = $row["course_name"];
    }
}
```

I know this is disgustingly inefficient and would like some help on revising it. I would just like to have the name pulled from other table where ID=?? (EX 1, 2, 6, and 320).

Is this the only way?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is an expression, not just a single column=value pair. `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 6 OR id = 320`. There are lots of ways to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $ids) . ")";

//Process as usual...
```

Comment: I've always had problems with IN because it would not accept duplicates?

What would be your suggestion on this?

Comment: It will accept duplicates, and you can remove the duplicates from your array with one function call... [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Handled the duplicates before passing the array to the query?

Comment: To remove duplicates: $array_unique_elements = array_unique($array_with_duplicates);

Comment: What I meant is, sometimes duplicate values need to be called and need them named otherwise they do not output properly?

Comment: Lets say $ids was 1,1,2,3 there would be an issue with 1 being called, only 1 of them would be.